# Publish/Target npm package for different node versions

Tags: node.js, npm

I have written a node module using ES7 features. I've also created a build script which transpiles to ES5.

Is there a way to publish the module, so that a node 8/9 user uses the original code and older node versions use the transpiled code?

The reason why I want this, is because I expect a better performance on the none transpiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the perfomance differnce between the transpiled code and ES7 code is negligible.

So it suffices to just publish the transpiled code.